# Unable to get phoneNumber from BroadcastReceiver even if BroadcastReceiver receiving all incomingnumber

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephony, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I placed below code in BroadcastReceiver and this code trigger every time when a new call arrives. But bundle not contains incoming_number. By printing out the bundle I get **Bundle[{state=RINGING}]**  as output. and I only get this problem in new phones(>= Android 9.0)

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
System.out.println("Kokp 1:- " + bundle);
String phoneNumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation indicates that `EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` is only populated if your app has the following permissions:

> This extra is only populated for receivers of the
> ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED broadcast which have been granted the
> Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG and
> Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permissions.